# Change struct values from a different class

Tags: c#-4.0, reference, struct

I am trying to change a struct values (located in class A) from another class (class B per say) I wrote a method to get the struct (the method is located in class A) but all I get is a shallow copy (the values do not really change...) any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's what happens with structs. You need to make the changes locally, then shallow copy *back* again. For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Point Location { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    private Foo foo = new Foo();

    public void MoveFoo()
    {
        Point location = foo.Location;
        location.X += 10;
        location.Y += 20;
        // Copy it back
        foo.Location = location;
    }
}
```

Personally I try to avoid making structs mutable in the first place - but will often given them what I call "pseudo-mutator" methods which return a new value with appropriate changes. So for example, for a `Point` struct I might have a method like this:

```
public Point TranslatedBy(int dx, int dy)
{
    return new Point(x + dx, y + dy);
}
```

Then the `MoveFoo` method above would be:

```
foo.Location = foo.Location.TranslatedBy(10, 20);
```

Comment: I ended up using a class instead..It solved the pointers problem plus I might need to add some methods inside so a class will be more appropriate...TNX anyway!